# Vertical alignment of \mathsmaller letters

Tags: vertical-alignment, letters, relsize

Some context: In denoting a perturbation of a matrix, `$A+\Delta A$` (in `$$` or `\[\]`), I do not like how large the Δ is. Makes `$\Delta A$` look like "Δ times $A$" rather than a descriptive prefix showing that ΔA is an irreducible entity.

Towards that end, I have tried to use `\mathsmaller` from `relsize` to fix the problem.

```
\[ \Delta A \qquad\text{versus}\qquad \mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{\Delta}}A\]
```

with output:

[image]

This gives the size I'd like, but the small Δ is flush to the bottom of A. I would like for it to be flush with the vertical center of A, like this:

[image]

Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notation such as Δ*A* has been used for a few centuries with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Notation such as “Δ*A*” or “Δ*x*” has been used for a few centuries with no problem of interpretation (perhaps by newbie students, not by professional mathematicians).

If you want to be original `;-)`, you can do it like

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SDelta}{{\mathpalette\center@smaller{\Delta}}}
\newcommand{\center@smaller}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1A$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th\center@smaller@style{#1}#2$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr(\ht\z@-\ht\tw@)/2\relax}{\copy\tw@}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\center@smaller@style}[1]{%
  \ifx\scriptstyle#1\scriptscriptstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\SDelta A_{\SDelta A}$

\end{document}
```

This works in first level subscripts or superscripts, but not second level.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something of this type? I hope to have understood your request.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny $\Delta$}A
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the `\Delta` symbol with a triangle symbol similar to `\Delta`, my suggestion is to use `MnSymbol` package that you can find in the pag. 68, Table 134: **MnSymbol Triangle Relations** into the guide of "[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)"

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny $\medtriangleup$}A
\end{document}
```